# Periodically obtaining/updating and comparing data in android?

Tags: android

I am creating an android application which obtains the local weather forecast from a weather api as well as twitter updates on the aurora borealis and correlates the two. I was wondering what is the best way for me to continually update the data and compare it, even when the user does not have the application open on their device? So essentially I want my app to run in the background. Any help would be great!

Comment: dont compare data in the device compare it in your server. If the data is changed then send update to device via GCM or similar techniques

Comment: I agree with @IllegalArgument. This sort of task is better done on the server. Not only do you not have to worry about battery power, in this case, you can also combine the information from all registered apps to get a better overall picture.

Answer (score 0):

The task you want to repeat periodically may be implemented in a IntentService.

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {

    public MyService () {
        super("MyService ");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        new MyTask().execute();
        Log.d("MyService", "About to execute MyTask");
    }

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {
            Log.d("MyService", "Calling doInBackground within MyTask");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

You need to set a periodic alarm through the AlarmManager, that allow you to decide when to start the IntentService using a PendingIntent; for example, in an activity:

```
...
int interval =10*1000;//every 10 seconds
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, MyAlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent =PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 
                          interval, pendingIntent);
...
```

The PendingIntent will be sent to an BroadcastReceiver listening for the alarm:

```
public class MyAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public MyAlarmReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
        Log.d("MyAlarmReceiver", "Called context.startService");
    }
}
```

Everytime phone is turned off, the alarms you set are automatically canceled, so you need a BroadcastReceiver listening for [boot_completed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) e setting again the alarm:

```
public class MyBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public MyBootReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.d("MyBootReceiver ", "Boot completed");
        int interval =10*1000;//every 10 second
        AlarmManager alarm = 
           (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, MyAlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = 
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

        alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
                                  System.currentTimeMillis(), 
                                  interval, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

In AndroidManifest.xml you need to add the RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED permission and the BOOT_COMPLETED intent-filter for the BroadcastReceiver :

```
<application ...>
    ...
    <receiver
    android:name=".services.MyBootReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true" >
    <intent-filter android:priority="500" >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    ...
</application>
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

More detail [here](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html)